# Check/uncheck checkbox depending on what checkboxes are checked (if/else)

Tags: jquery, if-statement

At the moment I'm working on a small jQuery element. I have 2 main checkboxes: ja and nee. When one of the boxes is checked, a submenu opens up and the checkboxes in the submenu are filled in according to which main checkbox you check (ja or nee). This works fine.

In the submenu the user can choose ja or nee with the set of check boxes that were populated with the initial click. The problem I'm having, is that when the user first checks the main checkbox to "nee" and then changes the checkboxes in the submenu to "ja", the main checkbox stays at "nee".

So I'm thinking I could fix this with a if/else statement but I can't figure out how to do it. I made it so that all the checkboxes have a state "checked" or no state when not checked, they also have classes ("ja" and "no").

This is the jQuery code I'm using now

```
$('.open_sub_ja').click(function () {
                $(this).parents('.container_vragen').find('.ja').attr('checked', this.checked);
                $(this).parents('.container_vragen').find('.nee').removeAttr('checked');
            });

            $('.open_sub_nee').click(function () {
                $(this).parents('.container_vragen').find('.ja').removeAttr('checked');
                $(this).parents('.container_vragen').find('.nee').attr('checked', this.checked);
            });

                $('.ja').click(function () {
                    $(this).parents('.antwoorden').find('.ja').attr('checked', this.checked);
                    $(this).parents('.antwoorden').find('.nee').removeAttr('checked');
                });

                $('.nee').click(function () {
                    $(this).parents('.antwoorden').find('.ja').removeAttr('checked');
                    $(this).parents('.antwoorden').find('.nee').attr('checked', this.checked);
                });
```

A small jsFiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/Macjm/. Any help is well helpfull for I have very little knowledge on the if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems here:

1. You need to be able to track which `ja` or `nee` inputs are checked in relation to the other checked `ja` or `nee` inputs of the sub menu.
2. You need to be able to check the parent `ja` or `nee` input when the count is equal to the number of sub menu `ja` or `nee` inputs.

One way to do this is with a few variables and some extra checks.

I will cover the case of the `ja` inputs here. The same process is used for the `nee` inputs.

To start In the `.ja` click function I added two variables after your existing code:

```
var _ja = $(this).parents('.submenu').find('.ja');
var _jaCount = 0;
```

`_ja` is a jquery object of all the sub menu `ja` inputs. `_jaCount` is a variable used to keep track of how many of the `ja` inputs were checked.

Then I do a check like this:

```
_ja.each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
        _jaCount++;
    }
});
```

Here I iterate through all the sub menu `ja` inputs and check to see if they are checked. If they are I increment my coutner by 1.

After this check I have the following statment:

```
if(_jaCount == _ja.length){
    $('.open_sub_ja').prop('checked',true);
    $('.open_sub_nee').prop('checked',false);
}else{
    $('.open_sub_ja').prop('checked',false);
    $('.open_sub_nee').prop('checked',false);
}
```

What this does is check to see if the count is equal to the amount of `ja` inputs in the sub menu. If it is it sets the paret `ja` input to checked and the parent `nee` input to unchecked. Furthermore if the count is not equal it sets both of the parents to unchecked because then you have a mixed state. If this is not desirable then you simply have to remove the else case.

In this way you can link the submeu `ja` input states to the parent state.

[Here is a modified version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ymBG3/3/)